# Java Unified Expression Language sub-expressions

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, el

I have a datatable which provides objects from a list. Within this data table I would like to use a tag like `p:columns(primefaces)` which provides strings from a list that represent the name of a field.

I will now need a subexpression to be able to use the dynamic field name like:

```
#{entry.#[column.fieldName}}
```

Is there any possibility to do this in JSF2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If entry has get/set accessors for columns values, you could use this syntax :

```
#{entry[column.fieldName]}
```

In EL you can use two syntaxes to access to the value of the "lastname" property of an object :

```
#{myObject.lastname}
#{myObject["lastname"]}
```

You can take a look to [JSPIntro at oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

Comment: I have just though of something like that and it worked, i was just not sure, because nowhere the term subexpression is mentioned in the reference and before i have never used this kind of feature in production.

Answer (score -1):

No, EL doesn't work like that.

What you could do to achieve the desired functionality would be this:

```
#{entry.getField(column.fieldName)}
```

where `getField()` is a method that uses reflection (perhaps via [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html)) to access the field with the given name. However, this is an EL 2.2 feature, so you'll need a pretty recent EL implemetation, such as provided by Tomcat 7.